# Angular 2: Use input property to define target element

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a tooltip component that I'd like to accept an `input` with an element reference but I amn not sure how to wire it up.

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip',
  templateUrl: 'tooltip.html'
})
export class TooltipComponent {

  @Input() el: string;

  target_el: any;

  constructor() {
     // do something with `el`
  }
}

// View
<tooltip [el]="'#a'">Hello</tooltip>
<button #a>I'm a button</button
```

I think I have to use `@ViewChild` but I'm not sure how to implement with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[style.top.xp]='top'`, Just pass a number you want as an input, or calculate it somehow

Comment: I'm trying to define an element